Is there another way to search for empty cell and offset when only one row of data exist?
Sub Archive()
    ' This archives the data to master list.
    Range("A2").Copy  
    Range("M1").Select
        If Range("M1") = "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Else: Range("M1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
   End If
End Sub

The problem I am having is with offset, When a blank archive WS is called upon, it gives me the run time errorrun time 1004. When I have 2 rows of data the code works perfectly. I simply need another way to move( offset) one row down with one row of data.  Without having to create/call a procedure for the first row.
I know this contains select
